# A conformal map whose Jacobian vanishes at a point is constant?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry, quasiconformal-maps

Let $f:M \to N$ be a smooth weakly conformal map between connected $d$-dimensional Riemannian manifolds, i.e. $f$ satisfies $df^Tdf =(\det df)^{\frac{2}{d}} \, \text{Id}$.

> Assume $d \ge 3$ and that $df=0$ at some point.  Is it true that $f$ is constant?

A proof for the Euclidean case, can be found in "Geometric Function Theory and Non-linear Analysis", by Iwaniec and Martin.

Comment: Have you tried redoing the Euclidean proof? If yes, where did you get stuck? It's a little hard to judge whether something new would be needed without knowing anything about that proof.

Comment: That is a fair question. I will try to describe tomorrow the Euclidean proof. Do you happen to know a reference for the general case?

Comment: No, I didn't even know a reference for the Euclidean result before seeing this. There is a chance I will have some intuition as to whether the Euclidean proof would work as such on a Riemannian manifold, but it depends on the kinds of arguments used.

Comment: Every conformal map between open non-empty subsets of Euclidean spaces of dimension $\ge 3$ is the restriction of a Möbius transformation by Liouville's theorem, which seems to imply this result directly for the Euclidean case. Liouville's proof turns the equations for conformality into a system of ODEs whose unique solutions are Möbius transformations. This proof can not quite work directly in the manifold case, so it does not immediately shed much light on the question.